# Lifetime of std::thread arguments

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stl

When parameters are passed to `std::thread()`, does the thread from which the new thread is being spawned wait until all the parameters are completely copied into new thread local storage?

Simple example:

```
void f()
{  
  int array[10];
  ........ //done something with array  
  std::thread th(someF, array); //assuming that someF accepts int[]  
  th.detach();  
}
```

Should I automatically assume that all the data is safely copied before `f()` has ended? 
One of the scenarios I see, assuming `f()` doesn't wait, and plows full steam ahead, is that `th` is attempting to copy `array` that is being in destroyed.

Comment: You aren't passing an array to that thread, you're passing a pointer to the first element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If it fails to copy it will throw in the constructing thread.

> *§30.3.1.2 thread constructors*
>
> template  explicit thread(F&& f, Args&&...
>   args);
>
> *Requires:* F and each Ti in Args shall satisfy the
>   MoveConstructible requirements. INVOKE (DECAY_- COPY (
>   std::forward(f)), DECAY_COPY (std::forward(args))...)
>   (20.8.2) shall be a valid expression. 4
>
> *Effects:* Constructs an object
>   of type thread. The new thread of execution executes INVOKE (DECAY_-
>   COPY ( std::forward(f)), DECAY_COPY (std::forward(args))...)
>   **with the calls to DECAY_COPY being evaluated in the constructing thread**. Any return value from this invocation is ignored. [ Note:
>   **This implies that any exceptions not thrown from the invocation of the copy of f will be thrown in the constructing thread, not the new
>   thread**. —end note ] If the invocation of INVOKE (DECAY_COPY (
>   std::forward(f)), DECAY_COPY (std::forward(args))...)
>   terminates with an uncaught exception, std::terminate shall be called.
>
> *Synchronization:* **The completion of the invocation of the
>   constructor synchronizes with the beginning of the invocation of the
>   copy of f.**

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if the arguments cannot be copied, to storage available to the new thread, it will throw an exception.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread

> Any exceptions thrown during evaluation and copying/moving of the
>   arguments are thrown in the current thread, not the new thread.

Comment: Note, however, that the correct term is **not** thread-local storage. They are copied to storage accessible to the thread. "Thread-local" storage is a different, and somewhat controversial, notion.

Comment: I noticed that peculiarity, too, but the referenced page has this, verbatim: "Creates new std::thread object and associates it with a thread of execution. First the constructor copies/moves all arguments args... to thread-local storage"  Perhaps it's wrong, or there's more to this?  I'll edit the answer to avoid the confusion.

Comment: Yes, that mention of "thread-local storage" is wrong. Thread-local storage is essentially per-thread static storage (i.e., each thread has its own copy of the thread-local data, which can be used by name from any function in the thread). The thread arguments are passed as ordinary arguments to the called function.

Comment: FYI, that page's reference to "tread-local" has been changed to "thread-available".